# How do I make my Flutter app expose 2 launcher entry points?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm building a Flutter app, caring mostly about Android for now. I want to expose 2 entry points, which in the classic Android world would be two activities declared in the Manifest with:

```xml
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

I tried to find instructions for the equivalent for Flutter, but did not find much documented. I'm guessing I would have to add a new activity in the Android project and somehow start my activity with a route following the documentation about [intent handling](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter)? It seems a bit hacky and I didn't get it working yet, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Found a way:

1. In `main.dart`, add a second method next to the classic `main()`. For example I did this:

```
void main() {
  _mainInternal();
}

void mySecondaryMain() {
  _mainInternal(initialRoute: '/foo');
}

void _mainInternal({String initialRoute}) {
  // ...
  runApp(MyApp(initialRoute: initialRoute));
}
```

2. Register a secondary launcher Activity as standard on Android: make sure to set the default activity, set the filters, a label and name of the activity, etc.
3. In that second activity, specify the different entry point to use to start the Flutter app

```
  override fun getDartEntrypointFunctionName(): String {
    return "mySecondaryMain"
  }
```

And this should work. I followed pointers from the flutter wiki links below:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Launch-Flutter-with-non-main-entrypoint
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Add-Flutter-Activity#launch-flutteractivity